# $\tan z=az+b$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to prove following questions.

> Prove that, for all complex numbers $(a,b)\neq (0,\pm i)$, the equation $\tan z = az + b$ has infinitely many solutions.

By assuming $(a,b)=(1,0)$, I tried to show $\tan x=x$ in real numbers and generalize it to complex numbers. But I feel like there is something missing in this assumption. Please help, I couldn't find a way out.

Comment: Do you mean that $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: yes, z is a complex number here.

Comment: Well then assuming that $(a,b)=(0,1)$ does not restrict to the real numbers, you simply have the case that $tan(z)=z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you know anything about the representation of complex numbers as $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: I have tried this representation also, still couldn't continue.